# BPM and ACTIVITI; Concepts and Terminology

Tags: java, business-process-management, activiti

Greeings,

I have to develop an application for a local govern. establishment for their budget monitoring and control and automating the processes for requesting and approving project proposals and budgets.

I tried to look at Activiti to handle the automation part, but so far I have not seen any resource that talks about mapping the theory to the practical.

I have few questions I'm going to just lay them out there hoping someone will give me a better picture.

1. is the Activiti Explorer meant to be used as the Inbox for all the different parties involved in a process?
2. from Activiti Explorer, what is a Task? Process? Event?
3. is there a centralized way of managing all the different processes-in-progress? for example, someone is not at his office or on a leave and all pending approvals has to be rerouted to someone else temporarly. can this be done with Activiti Explorer?

Comment: Try jBPM all these features are there in jBPM as far as the concern about re-routing your work to someone else when you are on leave it, you can write time based event in it where if it isn't achieved for 24 hours then it will be notified to someone else i.e Admin.

Comment: Here is the link http://www.jboss.org/jbpm‎ you will find answers about Process, task and event in the jbpm documentation.